# google sheets append data to sheet api returning 401 authentication error

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

When i request to append data to google sheet it returns 401 authentication error.
I have tried it using oauth (access token) and with api key but all time its returns 401 authentication error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you are making requires Oauth2 Authentication.  the key parameter is for adding api keys.  Api keys only allow for access to public api data.

you should be using access_token= with a valid Google Oauth2 access token.